# @Autowired does not create members in constructor

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean that is created from context, after which a autowired member is created:

```
@Service
public class FileDownloadService extends WFWFileDownloadService {
    @Autowired
    ConfigurationManager configurationManager;
```

When I use in code manual constructor call:

```
FileDownloadService fileDownloadService = new FileDownloadService();
```

I see configurationManager is null, so I have to make manual wiring:

```
    public FileDownloadService() {
        configurationManager = new ConfigurationManagerImpl();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong to make autowiring working with manual creating?

Comment: does ConfigurationManager  is @Component ? you use component scan ?
please provide information such as application context , web.xml 
thanks .

Comment: I see Donal's idea below about difference between BEAN and OBJECT. Let's try to go this way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the constructor directly, you're just creating an object and *not* a bean. The support of the `@Autowired` annotation is a feature of bean.

Ask the Spring context for the bean.

Comment: Or have the service injected by Spring into the calling object

Comment: Could you make an example for me how to get context?

Comment: it's a bad practice from my point of view ...
spring keep it simple with annotation ...
every other change just make it complicated

Comment: @mad: Are you getting the bean from another bean or from general code? (Please let it be the former; that's *much* easier!)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to make some other architect to use beans instead of objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to get the bean by using `new` operator, you will get all `autowired` beans inside that class as `null`.

Your service class is annotated with `@Service`, so to use it you should autowire this service class also.

Sample code to access service bean in other classes is :

```
@Controller or @Component
public class OtherClass {

    @Autowired FileDownloadService fileService;

    public void download() {
        fileService.downloadFile();
    }

}
```

In order this class to be able to autowire other beans, this class itself should be annotated with `@Controller` or `@Component`.

Comment: thanks but my question is about other. Please see Donal's answer. He is in point. If you would make an example for me then I will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is simple: 
If you manually create the Object, there is no wiring involved. How should Spring know, that you are in need for wiring? Instead of using new, you could use the getBean() method of the application context (Bean Factory). http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html